# Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device

Tags: html, video, streaming

I’m trying to stream an .MP4 from a mobile website. They run fine from my desktop but not on my phone , I get, “Sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device.” On my 2.2 Android and “Sorry, we can’t’ play this file on your phone” on the Windows emulator.

This is my video embed code, it’s doing it the HTML5 way.

```
<video 
    src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" 
    poster="http://www.mysite.com/myMobileSite/Content/Images/icon5.png" 
    type="video/mp4" 
    width="400" height="300" controls>
</video>
```

I can play “Video For Everybody” and other videos I’ve found on the net but I can’t play mine, which leads me to believe there is something wrong with a codec??? Or the way I’ve converted them from .AVI. but bear in mind the MP4s do play via the HTML5 MVC Razor webpage on my desktop, just not in the phones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be closed now for some reason but I have the answers can I share them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently html5 video and audio support is a whole new world of pain and compatibility problem - caught in a grid lock between the big internet companies. A great guide would be Mark Pilgrim's great book diveintohtml5.
The [chapter](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) about audio and video encoding, support etc. should solve you problem or lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have a [read of this](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) and see it it helps?

I suggest removing the `src` attribute from the `video` element and adding a `source` element that points to the MP4 file.